# Round up current time to next 15 mins interval in SQL or PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I want the current time to round up to the next 15 mins interval.

Eg: If I open the app with the current time as 8:53 pm, I want the next 15 mins round-up time to be 9:00 pm.

If the current time is 11:30 pm, the next round up time should be 11:45 pm.

How can I get next round time using sysdate in SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle's PL/SQL? What is your real DBMS?

Comment: PLSQL is oracle db, MySQL is owned by oracle but is not oracle db; please decide which db you're using

Comment: Open the app implies there is a front end; surely it should decide what the time is, not the server?

Comment: Note that an RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag **only** the database you are really using.

Comment: @astentx I am working on Oracle PL/SQL and the link you suggested rounds off to the nearest 15 minutes, I want to round off to the next 15 min, although it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Select Sysdate + (15/60)* rownum from dual

Comment: Please, do not post code-only answers. You can check this help article: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And this solution doesn't round-up the time to 15 minutes, it just adds 6 hours (15/60*24)

Comment: This query returns `10-FEB-21`.